# How to configure auto reconnection with hikari in SpringBoot application?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

We are using SpringBoot 2.1.x version so Hikari is the default DataSource implementation. However, I am not sure how to configure Hikari settings to auto reconnect to our Oracle database after database maintenance/restart or network connection issue.

We have the following hikari settings but it does not seem to help.

```
account.datasource.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:DEV
account.datasource.username: user
account.datasource.password: xxxx
account.datasource.driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

account.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout: 30000
account.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size: 3
account.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout: 60000
account.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime: 1800000
account.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle: 2
```

It failed to reconnect after network connection to the database got restored.

Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30033ms.

Any other account.datasource.hikari.xxxxx will help to auto reconnect to the database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the HikariCP [docs](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby):

> connectionTestQuery
>
> If your driver supports JDBC4 we strongly
>   recommend not setting this property. This is for "legacy" drivers that
>   do not support the JDBC4 Connection.isValid() API. This is the query
>   that will be executed just before a connection is given to you from
>   the pool to validate that the connection to the database is still
>   alive. Again, try running the pool without this property, HikariCP
>   will log an error if your driver is not JDBC4 compliant to let you
>   know. Default: none

So I'd suggest verifying that your JDBC Driver is actually JDBC4 compliant. If it's not - set the above property.

Comment: 2019-07-19 08:26:24.158 --- com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-07-19 08:26:24.161 --- com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource: Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2019-07-19 08:26:25.375 --- com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase: HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
2019-07-19 08:26:25.430 --- com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

Comment: Thanks. I see no error in the log so JDBC 4 complaint , right ?

Comment: We found out the problem our re-connecting issue. The above setting actually took care of the auto reconnecting. However, we have a network server issue internally that caused various issues including the reconnecting one. Good job Hikari data source.